# Server cannot process .php files - downloads them instead

Tags: windows-server-2003, php, iis-6

I am running IIS 6.0 on Windows Server 2003 using FastCGI. I have followed the instructions here:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/install.windows.iis6.php

including this line in my command prompt:

cscript %windir%\system32\inetsrv\fcgiconfig.js -add -section:"PHP" ^ -extension:php -path:"C:\PHP\php-cgi.exe"

However, my server does not recognise .php files. How do I configure my server to send php files to the php-cgi.exe, instead of downloading them?

Question is copied from 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6905811/server-cannot-process-php-files-downloads-them-instead

Comment: have you tried restarting the server?

Comment: PHP appears to be working. I can run my hello world program from the command prompt using php.exe and php-cgi.exe. The issue seems to be getting the server to associate php files with the executable.

Comment: @jeune No. It would take down an unknown number of services on my business, so I'd leave that as a last resort. Any other ideas what is causing the problem?

Comment: You can always align with your services that you will have a down time  of say 10 minutes to restart. Isn't that possible?

Comment: it might be a webserver issue, setting your file handler to php extensions.

Comment: FYI I've restarted Internet Services, and the browser still displays the open/save file dialog when I double click a php file. How do I set my file handler to handle php extensions?

Comment: In my IIS Manager, I right clicked Web Sites -> Properties -> Set "Execute Permissions" to "Scripts Only". Also, in Configurations, ".php" is set to the php-cgi.exe.

Answer (score 1):

If you open your IIS manager and browse to "Web Service Extensions" under your server, do you see "PHP ISAPI" in the right pane?

(from here: http://www.iisadmin.co.uk/?p=4&page=2)

Comment: I only have PHP pointing to php5.dll. What is the ISAPI? I downloaded PHP version 5.3 and I don't have the phpisapi.dll that a ton of guides mention.

Comment: How did you install PHP?